# Cannot secure PDF download route Route[login] not defined - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, laravel-passport

Currently I am working on a vue/laravel project where only authorized users should be allowed to call a route that uses domPDF to generate and download a PDF file. Unfortunately when I put the route inside `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){...})` in api.php, I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.
http://localhost:8000/api/qrsheets/1/download
```

This error only occurs for this specific route. The other routes with json-response inside this middleware function work fine, and when I access them I have an oAuth token inside my Authorization-header. I am using laravel's passport to have this token generated. What should be a simple and good solution for protecting this route?

**api.php**

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
     
        // QR SHEETS
        Route::get('/qrsheets/{id}/download', 'QrSheetController@downloadPDF')->name('qrsheets.download'); 
    });
```

**QrSheetController.php -> downloadPDF**

```
public function downloadPDF(Request $request){

    // find sheet by id
    $id = $request->route('id');
    $sheet = QrSheet::find($id);

    // set papaer width and height for pdf
    $paperWidthPt = $sheet->page_width_mm * (72 / 25.4);
    $paperHeightPt = $sheet->page_height_mm * (72 / 25.4);

    // set dimensions as paperformat
    $paperFormat = array(0,0,$paperWidthPt,$paperHeightPt);

    // create and download pdf
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('qrsheet.pdf-sheet', compact('sheet'))->setPaper($paperFormat, 'portrait');
    $filename = $sheet->alias . ".pdf";
    return $pdf->download($filename);
}
```

**AuthController.php -> login - just in case you need to know how token is generated**

```
    public function login(){
            if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
                $user = Auth::user();
                $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
                return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
            }
            else{
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized']);
            }
        }
```

kind regards,

Tim

Comment: It seems like you are being redirected to a login route, but that does not exist. If you run `php artisan route:list`, do you see the route it is looking for with the name `login`?

Comment: It sounds like you're maybe trying to use an href link on your frontend to download the pdf? but the route is using api authentication that requires a token, the link wont send a token so you get redirected to login, and then the error message about the login route not being defined. So you'd need to change to first making an axios request with token to get the pdf data, then use some functionality to provide that data as a downloadable pdf, or maybe use a session based authentication system for accessing the pdfs.